# Exception while analyzing expression in (3,54) in MainViewController.kt

Tags: ios, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

Exception while analyzing expression in (3,54) in /Users/patel/Desktop/Multiplatform/MultiplatformTest/composeApp/src/iosMain/kotlin/MainViewController.kt

Many time android studio gives this error how to get exact error in kotlin multiplatform when i try to build ios app.